# How to update firefox on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, updates, firefox

How can I update to firefox 42? There's nothing on the about page to update. I would like to update and keep all my settings and stuff. How can I go about doing this? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and currently using firefox 41. I'd like to avoid reinstalling but I guess I could if that would still save all my stuff. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Just wait, Firefox 42 should hit the updates very soon. In case you absolutely can't wait any longer, there is a [Mozilla PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), and it already has FF42.

Answer (score 1):

When a new version of Firefox comes out, there's a slight delay before it becomes available in the official repository. You can wait about a week for the update to get pushed out, or you can add the PPA for an unstable version.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion

Of course, you could always uninstall Firefox from the package manager and manually download from https://getfirefox.com. If you download it this way, all updates will be available as soon as Mozilla launches them. However, it's probably best to just wait a few days for the Ubuntu archives to update.

Edit: Firefox 42 is now available in the official Ubuntu archives. :)

Answer (score -1):

Okay click here and download FIrefox latest version [Firefox Download](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?product=firefox-3.6.8&os=osx%E2%8C%A9=en-US)